How to show this recursion for $\Big(\frac12(1+\sqrt{1-4x})\Big)^m$?

Let $a_n$ be the coefficients of the generating function $((1+\sqrt{1-4x})/2)^3$, i.e.,
$$
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}\right)^3 = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_nx^n.
$$
It is known, that $a_n$ satisfies the following recursion (see A115142 on OEIS, https://oeis.org/A115142)
$$
n(n-3)a_n - 2(n-2)(2n-5)a_{n-1} = 0.
$$

Let $b_n$ be the coefficients of the following generating function
$$
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}\right)^5 = \sum_{n \ge 0} b_nx^n.
$$
It is known that $b_n$ satisfies the following recursion (see A115144 on OEIS, https://oeis.org/A115144)
$$
n(n-5)b_n - 2(n-3)(2n-7)b_{n-1} = 0.
$$

More generally, let $m \ge 3$ be odd, and $c_n$ be the coefficients of the following power series
$$
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}\right)^m = \sum_{n \ge 0} c_nx^n.
$$
Then $c_n$ satisfies the following recursion
$$
n(n-m)c_n - 2\left(n-\frac{m+1}{2}\right)(2n-(m+2))c_{n-1} = 0.
$$
I have no reference for this result, which is guessed out according to the case $m=3,5$, and checked by a computer for the first several $c_n$ for $n$, say, in $[1,200]$ and odd $m \in [3,100]$.

The question is how can these results be shown? Thank you.



Abstractly, the existence of such recurrence relations is guaranteed from facts about D-finite functions. As noted in the OEIS entry A115140, the $m=1$ case is D-finite with recurrence relation specified therein. Since products of D-finite functions are also D-finite, the above products do indeed have suitable recurrence relations. But this doesn't constitute a proof of the particular relations in your question. (There exist algorithms for such calculations but they're beyond my expertise.)

You could consider the series as a MacLaurin series for $f$, your function in the title. Then the recurrence relation would be about the values of the derivates of $f$ for $x=0$. Not sure how easy the calculations would be, through.

Note that there is really nothing stopping us from
computing a closed form of
$$[x^n] \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}\right)^m.$$
This is
$$\;\underset{x}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}\right)^m.$$
Now we put $(1+\sqrt{1-4x})/2=v$ so that
$x=v(1-v)$ and $dx = (1-2v)\; dv$ to get
$$\;\underset{v=1}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1} (1-v)^{n+1}} v^m (-1-2(v-1))
\\ = (-1)^n \;\underset{v=1}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1} (v-1)^{n+1}} v^m (1+2(v-1)).$$
This will produce
$$(-1)^n \;\underset{v=1}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{(v-1)^{n+1}} (1+2(v-1)) \frac{1}{(1+v-1)^{n+1-m}}
\\ = (-1)^n \;\underset{v=1}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{(v-1)^{n+1}} (1+2(v-1))
\sum_{q\ge 0} {n-m+q\choose q} (-1)^q (v-1)^q.$$
Note that even when $m\ge n+1$ where we get a finite series
we still have the right expansion because by upper negation
${n-m+q\choose q} (-1)^q = {m-n-1\choose q}.$
This yields
$${2n-m\choose n} - 2  {2n-1-m\choose n-1}
= {2n-m\choose n} - 2 \frac{n}{2n-m} {2n-m\choose n}
\\ = - \frac{m}{2n-m} {2n-m\choose n}.$$
We thus have with $n\ge 1$ (the coefficient for $n=0$ is one)
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
c_{n,m} = - \frac{m}{n} {2n-m-1\choose n-1}.}$$
We were asked to show that
$$n(n-m) c_{n,m} - (2n-m-1)(2n-m-2) c_{n-1,m} = 0.$$
Multiplying by $n!$ we get
$$- n(n-m) m (2n-m-1)^{\underline{n-1}}
\\ + (2n-m-1)(2n-m-2) nm (2n-m-3)^{\underline{n-2}}
\\ = - n(n-m) m (2n-m-1)^{\underline{n-1}}
\\ + nm (2n-m-1)^{\underline{n}}
\\ = - n(n-m) m (2n-m-1)^{\underline{n-1}}
\\ + nm (n-m) (2n-m-1)^{\underline{n-1}} = 0.$$
This is the claim.

Is there a purpose for the underlined exponents in the last set of equation beyond emphasizing the different values?

@Semiclassical This is Knuth's notation for falling factorials, we have $n^{\underline{q}} = \prod_{r=0}^{q-1} (n-r).$ Also consult Concrete Mathematics.

The usual mechanical procedure is the following:
Start with the recurrence
$$
n(n-m)c_n - 2\left(n-\frac{m+1}{2}\right)(2n-(m+2))c_{n-1} = 0 
$$
, and sum over $x^n$ (we start the sum with index $n=1$ because the recurrence is first order):
$$
\sum_{n\geq1}{n\left(n-m\right)c_nx^n}-\sum_{n\geq1}{2\left(n-\frac{m+1}{2}\right)\left(2n-\left(m+2\right)\right)c_{n-1}x^n}=0
$$
Next, integrate, differentiate and do index shifts to get each summand into the form $F(x):=\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n x^n$.
For the first summand:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq1}{n\left(n-m\right)c_nx^n}\\&=\sum_{n\geq0}{n\left(n-m\right)c_nx^n}\\&=x\sum_{n\geq0}{n\left(n-m\right)c_nx^{n-1}}\\&=x\sum_{n\geq0}{\frac{d}{dx}\int{n\left(n-m\right)c_nx^{n-1}}dx}\\&=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\geq0}{\left(n-m\right)c_nx^n}\\&=x\frac{d}{dx}x^{m+1}\sum_{n\geq0}{\left(n-m\right)c_nx^{n-m-1}}\\&=x\frac{d}{dx}x^{m+1}\sum_{n\geq0}{\frac{d}{dx}\int\left(n-m\right)c_nx^{n-m-1}dx}\\&=x\frac{d}{dx}x^{m+1}\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\geq0}{c_nx^{n-m}dx}\\&=x\frac{d}{dx}x^{m+1}\frac{d}{dx}x^{-m}\sum_{n\geq0}{c_nx^ndx}\\&=x\frac{d}{dx}x^{m+1}\frac{d}{dx}x^{-m}F\left(x\right)
\end{align}  $$
For the second summand:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq1}{2\left(n-\frac{m+1}{2}\right)\left(2n-\left(m+2\right)\right)c_{n-1}x^n}\\&=\sum_{n\geq0}{2\left(n+1-\frac{m+1}{2}\right)\left(2n-m\right)c_nx^{n+1}}\\&=x^{\frac{m+1}{2}+1}\frac{d}{dx}2\sum_{n\geq0}{\left(2n-m\right)c_nx^{n+1-\frac{m+1}{2}}}\\&=x^{\frac{m+1}{2}+1}\frac{d}{dx}2\left(2\sum_{n\geq0}{nc_nx^{n+1-\frac{m+1}{2}}}-m\sum_{n\geq0}{c_nx^{n+1-\frac{m+1}{2}}}\right)\\&=x^{\frac{m+1}{2}+1}\frac{d}{dx}2\left(2\sum_{n\geq0}{nc_nx^{n+1-\frac{m+1}{2}}}-mx^{1-\frac{m+1}{2}}F\left(x\right)\right)
\\&
=x^{\frac{m+1}{2}+1}\frac{d}{dx}2\left(2x^{2-\frac{m+1}{2}}\frac{d}{dx}F\left(x\right)-mx^{1-\frac{m+1}{2}}F\left(x\right)\right)
\end{align}  $$
And with that all that's left to show is that with $F(x)=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}\right)^m $ we have that
$$x\frac{d}{dx}x^{m+1}\frac{d}{dx}x^{-m}F\left(x\right) = 
x^{\frac{m+1}{2}+1}\frac{d}{dx}2\left(2x^{2-\frac{m+1}{2}}\frac{d}{dx}F\left(x\right)-mx^{1-\frac{m+1}{2}}F\left(x\right)\right)
$$
, which is easily verified with a CAS.
